# Writing Spark Dataframe directly to HIVE is taking too much time

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am writing 2 dataframes from Spark directly to Hive using `PySpark`. The first df has only one row and 7 columns. The second df has 20M rows and 20 columns. It took 10 mins to write the 1 df(1row) and around 30Mins to write 1M rows in the second DF. I dont know how long it will take to write the entire 20M, I killed the code before it can complete.

I have tried two approaches to write the df. I also cached the df to see if it would make the write faster but didn't seem to have any effect:

```
df_log.write.mode("append").insertInto("project_alpha.sends_log_test")
```

2nd Method

```
#df_log.registerTempTable("temp2")
#df_log.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")
sqlContext.sql("insert into table project_alpha.sends_log_test select * from temp2")
```

In the 2nd approach I tried using both `registerTempTable()` as well as `createOrReplaceTempView()` but there was no difference in the run time.

Is there a way to write it faster or more efficiently. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the final tables are cached? It might be the issue that before writing the data it calculates the whole pipeline. You can check that in terminal/console where Spark runs.

Also, please check if the table you append to on Hive is not a temporary view - then it could be the issue of recalculating the view before appending new rows.
When I write data to Hive I always use:

```
df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table', mode='overwrite')
```

Please try:

```
df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table', mode='append')
```

Answer (score 1):

Its bad idea(or design) to do insert into hive table. You have to save it as file and create a table on top of it or add as a  partition to existing table.

Can you please try that route.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on `"add as a partition to existing table"`?

Comment: It is not necessarily true as per user asking question itself. Underline spark catalyst is same for df. Is there any spark developer note on this?

Answer (score 0):

try repartition to small number of files lets say like .repartition(2000)  and then write to hive. Large number of partitions in spark sometimes takes time to write.